# Why vscode print "undefined" as the result

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I think the console should return 34 for me,but I got "undefined" in the vscode ide.

[image]

I run below code in the chrome, then I got 34.

[image]

I want to know why,and if my settings is the reason, how should I modify the settings?

```
   function foo() {
        console.log( this.a );
    }

    var obj = {
        a: 2,
        foo: foo
    };

    var bar = obj.foo;

    var a = 34;

    bar();
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: I know the mechanism of "this", I just try to write a simple example in the vscode.I also know the result.But I don't got that in the vscode, so I just ask this question,It's about vscode not js.

Comment: Yes, I put function foo to the property of foo, and I put the obj.foo to the variable “bar”, and I called "bar" in the snippet last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have tested and as below pictures can show

`this` in Chrome Debugger referred to `window` but in VSCode it be an object which have some Symbol (for example variables names)

so the main reason is the difference behavior between VSCode debugger and Chrome.

In VSCode:
[image]

In Chrome:[image]

Comment: Yes you're right.I just realized this question.And thank you very much for solved my question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the output is 34 lies in **what exactly bar is**

And actually it's because `bar` points to the global function `foo`

Finally, when you call `bar()`, you don't actually call `obj.foo()`, but the global `foo`. And in JavaScript, the `this` value is only defined when you call the function and `this` is the context where you are calling the function, which is in this case, the `window`, and `window.a` points to 34.

There's nothing wrong with your settings.

Feel free to read this awesome article and leave your comment below!
[How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: So can you explain me that why above snippet in the vscode print "undefined"?

Comment: @ShawnLi The `undefined` is the return value of your global function `foo`, since it returns nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I regarded the undefine as the result of the function print.But I can't find the right result in the vscode.It's so strange.

Comment: Sorry, I just changed my code, when I delete the "this" keyword, console show "34", it's not return value